# Using Indirect formula in creating a dynamic dropdown list using a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown list. So far I have used the offset formula to create named ranges. Here is a sample.

Dynamic Range Name: CASH_ON_HAND

Dynamic Range: =OFFSET(GLSL01!$$C$11,0,0,COUNTA(tbl_GLSL01[CASH ON HAND]),1)

When creating the dropdown list, I can enter =CASH_ON_HAND in the data validation box and it works fine as shown in this image:
[DropDown List, Data Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZUL1.png)

However, that method would not be efficient so I need to use the INDIRECT formula so my dropdown list would depend on the value I select on one cell as shown in this image:

[Dynamic Dropdown List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj0XL.png)

So to my surprise, dynamic ranges do not work well with the indirect formula so my dynamic dropdown would not work. I am working with over 100 dynamic ranges so manually setting the data validation rules for the dropdown is out of the question.

[Name Manger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYpzs.png)

[Cash_on_Hand in Name Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svhOf.png)

[Indirect Fomula using a Dynamic Range Name whic depends on the value of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ICA.png)

[Error in using Indirect Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RXcK.png)

Is there any way that I can use my dynamic ranges inside the INDIRECT formula? I really need to make this work. I have browsed a lot of materials on the internet but none has made it work.

Comment: Use `=INDIRECT("CASH_ON_HAND")` on data validation list.

Comment: In case of cell reference use `=INDIRECT(C2)` for dynamic named range.

Comment: Hi @Harun24HR Thanks for replying. I already did that if you checked the images. So far it does not work so I am wondering if there are some workarounds.

Comment: `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(H2," ", "_"))` is working fine for me where`H2` contains "CASH ON HAND". By the way you are using `Named Range` or `Table`?. Remember if you use `Table` it will not work. You have to use `Named Range`

Comment: Your problem is you are using `TABLE`. Table range will not work on data validation list formula.

Comment: @Harun24HR I am using tables so every time there will be an additional item to any list, the same will be automatically added to my dropdowns. If I had to use normal ranges, then I have to make sure that everytime I add an item, I need to update my named range and that's too time consuming as well as very prone to error.

Comment: @Harun24HR I am not using table range in the validation list formula. I am using the indirect formula to call on my defined named range. This defined named range uses the offset formula which has a reference on a table which contains my list.

Comment: From `Name Manager` screenshot it is clearly showing you are using table `tbl_GLSL01`. That is the cause of not working. You can use dynamic name manger using `OFFSET()` formula instead of table. I have tested without table and it works fine. You can also test.

Comment: @Harun24HR I can give you a copy of my excel file because there maybe some sort of misunderstanding here. I have used offset formula. tbl_GLSL01 is indeed a table. A column in that table "CASH ON HAND" is a part of my OFFSET formula which is the "Refer To" of my CASH_ON_HAND named range. Indirect formulas work fine when referring to a table. if I make a named range CASHONHAND with the refer to refering to the column CASH ON HAND in the table tbl_GLSL01, it works fine. If i use the offset formula so blanks will not be included in the CASH ON HAND column, that is when INDIRECT does not work.

Comment: Please share a sample file. I will have a look into it.